# How to expose interceptors to JMX?

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

Is it possible to expose an interceptor to JMX?. Eg:

if i have following interceptor as:

```
<interceptor name="interceptorRef" class="some.package.class.Inteceptor"/>
```

and being used as:

```
<interceptor-stack name="interceptorStack">
     <interceptor-ref name="interceptorRef"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

I want this interceptor to be exposed to JMX? Is it possibe? How can that be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you encountering an error?

Comment: yes... Eric there was some error... I wanted to know if this is possible or not?

Comment: Please post the said error in your question.

Comment: Without more info, it should be possible provided you interceptor is declared as a Spring bean (as you have `interceptor-stack` I assume you use Struts2)

Comment: i was not able to use interceptor bean inside interceptor-stack...

Answer (score 0):

Any spring bean can exposed via JMX. In this case if you are using Struts2 and

- have configured struts's object factory to be spring
- added @ManagedResource/@ManagedOperation/@ManagedAttributes to the class
- added the context:mbean-export directive in your spring file

then the operations on the said interceptor should be accessible via JMX.